# cancelling a thread inside a signal handler 

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have started a timer and set the interval as 5 secs and registered a signal handler for it. 
When SIGALRM is encountered  iam trying to terminate the thread inside the signal handler, bt not able to do that. Thread is not getting terminated , instead of this whole process is killed.
The following is the code:

```
 void signalHandler()
{
        printf("Caught signal ...\n");
        printf("Now going to terminate thread..\n");
        pthread_kill(tid, SIGKILL);
}

void * thread_function()
{
        int oldstate;
        char result[256] = {0};
        time_t startTime = time(NULL);
        time_t timerDuration = 5;
        time_t endTime = startTime + timerDuration;

        while(1) {
                printf("Timer is runnuing as dameon..\n");
                if(!strcmp(result, "CONNECTED")) {
                        resp = 1;
                        pthread_exit(&resp);
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        int *ptr[2];

        signal(SIGALRM, signalHandler);

        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
        timer.it_interval. tv_usec = 0;

        timer.it_value.tv_sec = INTERVAL;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, 0);
            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
        pthread_join(tid, (void**)&(ptr[0]));
        printf("test %d\n\n",*ptr[0]);

        while(1)
                printf("1");
}
```

Platform : Linux , gcc compiler

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware you pretty much can't call anything inside a signal handler as you don't know what state your code is in.

Your best option is to set up a thread to handle your signals. All your other threads should call `pthread_setsigmask` and to block all signals, and then you create another thread, which calls calls `pthread_setsigmask` to catch `SIGALARM`, and then calls `sigwait`, at which point it can cancel the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

The way of handling signals is much different in a multi-threaded environment as compared to a single threaded environment. In a multi-threaded code, you should block out all the signals for all the threads that have your business logic and then create a seperate thread for handling the signals. This is because, in multi-threaded environment, you cannot be sure to which thread the signal will be delivered.

Please refer to this link for more details: 
http://devcry.heiho.net/2009/05/pthreads-and-unix-signals.html

Apart from this, to kill a thread use [pthread_cancel](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) which should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a flag:

```
int go_on[number_of_threads] = { 1 };

void signalHandler()
{
        printf("Caught signal ...\n");
        printf("Now going to terminate thread..\n");
        go_on[tid] = 0;
}

void * thread_function()
{  /* */
   while(go_on[this_thread_id]) {
                printf("Timer is runnuing as dameon..\n");
                if(!strcmp(result, "CONNECTED")) {
                        resp = 1;
                        pthread_exit(&resp);
                }
   }
}
```